# Getting error for generic interface: The interface Observer cannot be implemented more than once with different arguments:

Tags: java, gwt, observer-pattern

I am getting this error in Eclipse while writing a GWT app

> The interface Observer cannot be
>   implemented more than once with
>   different arguments:
>   Observer<CompositeListData > and
>   Observer<DialogBoxAuthenticate>

```
public class CompositeWordLists extends Composite implements Observer<DialogBoxAuthenticate>, Observer<CompositeListData>
```

Here is the interface

```
public interface Observer<T> {
    public void update(T o);
}
```

Is this right?  How can I get around this problem without having to create a multitude of Observer classes for every possible event?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because of type erasure you can't implement the same interface twice (with different type parameters). So, the eclipse error that you are receiving is correct.

You could add a base class for all possible "T", which may be limiting and not useful depending on the scope of these classes. And, you have requested a solution that prevents you from creating a multitude of Observer classes (i am assuming interfaces) for every possible event, well I can't see how else you would do that without compromising compile time safety.

I would suggest the following

```
interface Observer<T>{
    public void update (T o);
}

interface DialogBoxAuthenticateObserver extends Observer<DialogBoxAuthenticate>{
}
```

The code clutter isn't horrible and if you place them all in one file, they will be easy to reference and maintain. Hope I have helped

**EDIT**: After some digging around on google (which pointed me back to stackoverflow!, your question was asked in a different fashion and answered similarly [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1297972/how-to-make-a-java-class-that-implements-one-interface-with-two-generic-types)

Comment: So, I just tried this solution on my current (nearly identical) problem, and this solution didnt work.

Comment: You can't do that, either. You will get the same multiple interface error.

Answer (score 0):

Composite must already implement Observer. Is that what really intended? You want this CompositeWordLists class to observe two ways at once?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this can help, but I came across the same Java compile error today.

I partially solved my case by extracting all the shared implementation I could get to a *parametrized abstract class*:

```
public enum Example {
    ;
    static interface Observer<T> { public void update (T o); }
    static abstract AbstractObserver<T> implements Observer<T> {
        public void update (T o) { /* shared stuff I can put here */ }
    }
    static Composite extends AbstractObserver<Parameter1> {
        public void update (T o) {
            super(o);
            /* type-specific code here */
        }
    }
    static CompositeWordLists extends AbstractObserver<Parameter2> {
        public void update (T o) {
            super(o);
            /* type-specific code here */
        }
    }
}
```