# Instantiating generic class and implementing generic interface

Tags: java, generics, inheritance

I have this class:

```
public DrawItem {
    protected String getSeperator() {
        return "";
    }
    .......
    // some other methods
}
```

I've another class which extends `DrawItem`.

```
public DrawNumber extends DrawItem {
    @Override
    protected String getSeperator() {
        return "-";
    }
}
```

Now, in a generic class `CombinationGenerator<E>`, I'm trying to instantiate objects of `DrawItem`/`DrawNumber`. As instantiating a generic type is not possible in java (like `new E(...)`), I've created a Factory interface according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75528/1031888) answer.

```
public interface DrawItemFactory<E> {
    E create(...);
}
```

Then in the `CombinationGenerator<E>` class,

```
public class CombinationGenerator<E> {
    DrawItemFactory<E> factory;

    public CombinationGenerator<E>(DrawItemFactory<E> factory) {
        this.factory = factory;
    }

    public List<E> generate() {
        ......
        list.add(factory.create(...));
        ......
    }
}
```

And now the `DrawNumber` class implements `DrawItemFactory<DrawItem>` interface.

```
public DrawItem implements DrawItemFactory<DrawItem> {
    protected String getSeperator() {
        return "";
    }

    @Override
    public DrawItem create(...) {
        return new DrawItem(...);
    }
    .......
    // some other methods
}
```

And I can create `CombinationGenerator<DrawItem>` class.

```
DrawItem drawItem = new DrawItem(...);
CombinationGenerator<DrawItem> generator = new CombinationGenerator<DrawItem>(drawItem);
List<DrawItem> combinations = generator.generate();
```

So far, everything is fine. But when I try to create a `DrawNumber` class like this,

```
public DrawNumber implements DrawItemFactory<DrawNumber> {
     ....
}
```

It gives me the following error:

```
The interface DrawItemFactory cannot be implemented more than once with different arguments: DrawItemFactory<DrawItem> and DrawItemFactory<DrawNumber>
```

I've tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4282562/1031888) solution but I got the same error. Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: Why do you make DrawItem a factory of DrawItem? You would need a DrawIem to create a DrawItem. Quite strange. Use separate classes as factories.

Comment: Thanks.. solved the problem by creating two separate factory classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to @JB Nizet's comment, I've solved the problem by creating two separate factory classes like this:

```
public interface ItemFactory<E> {
    E create(int[] values);

    public static class DrawItemFactory implements ItemFactory<DrawItem> {

        @Override
        public DrawItem create(int[] values) {
            return new DrawItem(values);
        }           
    }

    public static class DrawNumberFactory implements ItemFactory<DrawNumber> {

        @Override
        public DrawNumber create(int[] values) {
            return new DrawNumber(values);
        }           
    }
}
```

In the `CombinationGenerator`,

```
public class CombinationGenerator<E> {
    ItemFactory<E> factory;

    public CombinationGenerator<E>(ItemFactory<E> factory) {
        this.factory = factory;
    }

    public List<E> generate() {
        ......
        list.add(factory.create(...));
        ......
    }
}
```

And instantiated `CombinationGenerator` like this:

```
DrawNumber drawNumber = new DrawNumber();
CombinationGenerator<DrawNumber> generator = new CombinationGenerator<DrawNumber>(new ItemFactory.DrawNumberFactory());

List<DrawNumber> combinations = generator.generate();
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using all those factories you could do something like this:

```
public class CombinationGenerator<E> {

    E instance;

    public CombinationGenerator(Class<E> clazz) {
        Constructor<?> con = clazz.getConstructor();
        this.instance = (E) con.newInstance();
    }
}
```

...
`CombinationGenerator<DrawNumber> cg = new CombinationGenerator<DrawNumber>(DrawNumber.class);`

Comment: Reflection is evil and promotes too tight binding to constructor/method signatures that are hard to refactor if necessary pretty much. Simple passing `Supplier<E>` and then invoking `.get()` gives much more freedom. `Function<E,T>` is an option either.